# Launching vim from `cmd` or `powershell` fails with a blank screen but works from `git bash`

Tags: git, powershell, vim, cmd

I have been using Git through the command line (cmd or powershell) for a few weeks now (I've been an avid SourceTree user). Everything has been working smoothly until now.

Now when I type `git commit` I am presented with what appears to be a blank screen rather than the default vim screen one would normally get where you enter your commit message. I cannot `<esc>:q!` out of it. However, if I continue pressing keys on the keyboard those keys eventually show up.

In fact, if I first hit `<esc>:q!` and then press a number of random keys the editor eventually pops up and immediately quits as `<esc>:q!` is processed.

I have confirmed this behavior with `> git commit` and plain old `> vim`. If I load vim without plugins via `vim -u NONE and -U NONE` I can use vim in the console.

FWIW. Vim, and vim through Git work fine in in the git bash console.

This would appear to be a buffering issue of some sort. How can I resolve this without resorting to reinstalling git? What may have caused this to happen?

Specs:

- Windows 10 (VM on VirtualBox)
- git version 2.8.0.windows.1
- VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (included with Git)

Comment: Do you need to type to get the screen to display or does just waiting work? Is this a vim startup delay issue?

Comment: @EtanReisner I need to type to get it to display.

Comment: Does it matter what you type? Do you need to hit Enter specifically? This sounds like a plugin/etc. might be triggering a prompt that you need to confirm but that isn't being displayed for some reason.

Comment: It does not matter what I type. I do not need to hit enter. On the 6th key press the `~` characters show up on the side. On the 9th key press the `VIM - Vi IMproved` title "screen" is shown along with the command area at the bottom. However, because of the character delay I am unable to successfully interact with it.

Comment: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/711 The issue is fixed in GfW 2.8.1. And please, checking the upstream's issue tracker should be the first thing to do; posting to upstream's venues for communication -- the second. SO is hardly fit for support requests to deal with bugs in software like this one.

Comment: @kostix, that was definitely it. And I agree w/ checking the upstream source first. It didn't even occur to me this could be a bug. I thought it had to be something that I caused.

Comment: That's okay, glad it helped! ;-)